# Show/Hide Multiple Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a show/hide of one div at a time.

What is happening is that all the divs (.shareLink) are opening at the same time.

Below is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".shareLink").hide();
$("a.trigger").click(function(){
$(".shareLink").toggle("400");
return false;
});
});
```

Below is my HTML:

```
<dl class="links">
    <dd>content</dd>
    <dt class="description">content</dt>
    <ul class="tools">      
        <li><a class="trigger" href="#">Share Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</dl>
<div class="shareLink">
<?php print check_plain($node->title) ?>
</div>
```

Any help with the above problem would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: please post how your HTML is setup, otherwise we can't really help you. As it is right now you are selecting everything with a class of shareLink and toggling it, so of course everything is opening.

Comment: It's also a good idea to format your source code according to accepted style conventions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style#Indenting
This makes it much easier for yourself and others to read & understand the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your HTML, you need to do this:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.shareLink").hide();
    $("a.trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('dl.links').next('div.shareLink').toggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This walks up to the parent DL and then moves over to the next shareLink div and toggles it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I put the wrong code in by accident. The actual code has now been pasted into my original post.

Comment: It is the same idea as before, just walking up further to the dl. I updated my code to show this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".shareLink").toggle("400");
```

Refers to any div on the page with a class of ".shareLink".

You will need to find a way to distinguish the specific div you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".shareLink").hide();
    $("a.trigger").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next().toggle("400");
    });
});
```

The answer is it depends on the structure of your document. Here is a sample of something that will work with the above function.

```
<a class="trigger">click here</a>
<div class="shareLink">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
</div>
```